# googleplus api giving nextPageToken even when there is not data

Tags: google-api, google-plus

Why is Googleplus api giving `nextPageToken` when there is no results ?

```
{
 "kind": "plus#activityFeed",
 "etag": "\"gLJf7LwN3wOpLHXk4IeQ9ES9mEc/E_vEAk7R5aEXkBfh8ZRN5jeozRI\"",
 "nextPageToken": "ChAQt73bzsytxwIYACCTASgHEg4IABAAGP__________fxgCIAAo0Z7qjYvxrPfUAQ==",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?orderBy=recent&pageToken=Cg8Qt73bzsytxwIYACB-KAYSDggAEAAY__________9_GAIgACjRnuqNi_Gs99QB==&key=AIzaSyDf3ejxhljBJ31CIRqx3-g7zXVTvq08HA0&query=%2B971-800-7669&alt=json&maxResults=20",
 "title": "Google+ Activities Search Results",
 "items": []
}
```